# Looking for a good book explaining how things work in the industrial system test environment and production environment

Tags: load-balance, builds, logging, cache

Any advice on a good book explaining how things work in the industrial system test environment and production environment?
It's my first time in this topic, so I would need a general overview.

Key words: builds, web logic levels, machines, clusters, logs, cache, balancers, UDC

(If you thing I posted this question in the wrong place, please, could you point me the right one? Thanks)

Comment: I previously posted this question on meta section of devops.stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

Dude, will depends of what you want to use or follow. Actually cloud + DevOps it's a buzzword in use.
So you can start reading about Cloud Architecture, Modern Infrastructure.
Refer about one book, maybe these: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030037116